# Ansible: how can I use a wildcard or an alternative?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I recently learned that it's not possible to use the wildcard on Ansible. So I would like to know how could I run the next command with a Role.

```
cat /sys/class/net/*/address | while read mac
```

I tried to do it so, but it doesn't work.

```
- name: Cat address file
  command: 'cat /sys/class/net/lo/address'
  register: my_items
  
- name: Cat address file 2
  command: 'cat /sys/class/net/enp2s0/address'
  register: my_items
  
- name: Cat address file 3
  command: 'cat /sys/class/net/wlo1/address'
  register: my_items

- name: Read address file
  command: read 
  with_items: my_items.stout_lines
```

Comment: The "wildcard" is actually a shell-glob, so you need a shell to use it. Use `shell` instead of `command`. In case it does not work, add `executable: /bin/bash` to that `shell`-task. Check the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whats your error but I used this and it works for me:

```
---
- hosts: dev
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: get mac
      shell: cat /sys/class/net/*/address
      register: items
    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{items.stdout_lines}}"
```

Result:
[image]